# Show limit does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show that this limit does not exist,
z is Complex number:
$\lim_{z \to -1 } \frac{1}{z^3}\sin (\frac{z}{z+1})$

Comment: How far did you get? where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think i find out how to show that. $2 \pi k = z/(z+1)$ so i will have the first series $Z_k$, that will give me $sin(2\pi k) = 0$

Comment: You should put your described attempt into the question. As you can see from my answer, it's not a bad start at all. Also, use `\sin` to get "$\sin$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a sequence for $z \to -1$ such that $2πk = \frac{z}{z+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{z+1}$. Can you now? You basically have to choose a sequence for $k$ so that the required $z$ tends to $-1$. So the original expression is zero on this sequence for $z \to -1$.

You also want another sequence for $z \to -1$ such that the original expression does not tend to zero. You can use the same trick to make $\sin(\frac{z}{z+1}) = 1$ on that sequence. Then the expression would not tend to zero.